# Please tell me what I am doing wrong because the value returned by monthstr2num is wrong

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

Please tell me what I am doing wrong

```
//I'm trying to get the number of the month by sending its name.
#include <stdio.h>
```

My function

```
int monthstr2num (char month[]){                                                


if (month == "September")
    return 8;


}

int main (){
char month []={"September"};
int num;

num = monthstr2num (month);//func call
```

displays a wrong output like 37814040

```
printf ("%d", num);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile your code with all warnings enabled (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g mehdi.c -o mehdi-prog` ? If you did, you should get warnings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in two places.

First is where you are using `==` to compare a string, that isn't possible in C (It's undefined behavior, it compiles but won't do what you want). You must use a function in the C library called `strcmp`. It's located in `string.h` and can be used like so:

```
if(strcmp(month,"September")==0)
    return 8;
```

Also, when that if statement returns false, you must have another return outside the if statement, such as `return 0;`

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code has 2 problems:

1) `(month == "September")` compares pointers and not the actual data

2)  when `(month == "September")` is false, the function returns some garbage, because there is no return statement for this case

Answer (score 0):

```
if (month == "September")
```

Is wrong. Use `strcmp`.  I'm a little surprised this compiles (as I'm not perfect in my array/pointer subtleties), but this will wind up comparing memory addresses of theses two entities as pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `==` to compare strings. C strings are a `char *`, and `==` will compare the pointers.

The C standard library provides functions for comparing C strings, e.g.: [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/), just `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: Technically ou could use `==` on `char*` values with a string literal, but it is undefined behavior, and a good compiler with all warnings enabled should give you a warning. However the code does compile (with an undefined behavior).